# java test runner for vs code stuck at resolving launch configuration

Tags: java, testing, visual-studio-code

A couple of days ago, everyone working on my project lost the ability to run tests directly from vs code test runner.  If you click on the green arrow, a dialog opens in the bottom right corner with the message, "Run Tests: Resolving launch configuration". After that, nothing happens.  The dialog box stays open forever.

dialog box image 
[image]

I can run tests using maven so this leads me to believe the java test runner plugin is broken.  Since everyone had the same problem at the same time and the tests run with maven, it seems that it must have something to do with an update.  Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated.

Update: I have narrowed the parameters down to test classes with more than one test method.  If there is just one test, it runs fine.  I just know this is going to be a forehead slapper when it is figured out.

this fails

```
package com.broken;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * This fails
*/
public class TestNgTwoTests {
    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        assertThat(true).as("I am the first test").isTrue();
    }
    @Test
    public void testTwo(){
        assertThat(true).as("I am the second test").isTrue();
    }
}
```

this works

```
package com.broken;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * This works
*/
public class JUnitTwoTests {
    
    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        assertThat(true).as("I am the first test").isTrue();
    }
    @Test
    public void testTwo(){
        assertThat(true).as("I am the second test").isTrue();
    }
}
```

this works

```
package com.broken;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * This works
*/
public class TestNgOneTest {
    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        assertThat(true).as("I am the first test").isTrue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is visible with 0.31.2 for TestNG project, See [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1284).

Sorry that there's no workaround or solutions now but it would be fixed in next release.

Comment: Is there any way to revert to an earlier version before the problem?

Comment: It looks like the issue was patched.  I am not seeing the problem this morning.

Comment: @LewisAyers. That's great, although this question still exists in my project, hope new version could be released soon.

Comment: Still facing the issue on v0.37.1